# Wordpress Testing - Efficient way of using Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Following question arises we had a testing session in wordpress core,

Which is the efficient way of using the wpdb class objects outputs in wordpress?

Example,
Getting wp users table name,

```
$wpdb->tables('all')['users']
```

**(or)**

```
$wpdb->users
```

In both of the above ways we can get the users table name, Why developers are preferring `$wpdb->users` more than `$wpdb->tables('all')['users']`,

Is there any specific reason in the efficiency and how can we test this out?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this specific code works, but I may assume that it is using a magic method __get in your wpdb object class.

According to this benchmark, using the magic methods is slower than using the standard methods ; [magic methods benchmarks](http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/magic-benchmarks). Therefore, it looks like in some cases, as the one you describe, it can be better in terms of code readability / maintenance to use a magic method.

I'm no expert in data structure and caching of object structures behind, but there might be some advantages to use the object properties directly instead of magic methods when it comes to opcaching as well, but I'm really not sure about this (a bit as using traditional methods instead of closures).

Comment: You have mentioned Magic methods are slower but developers are preferred to do things using Magic methods.. Is there any specific reliability for that?

Comment: Some developers prefer using magic methods because it makes the code more synthetic. Some other do not like it because it breaks your IDE autocompletion capability... In your specific example, it also allow the developer to have the code only once, so if one day you were to change the access to $wpdb->users to anything else than $wpdb->tables... (for instance replacing with a webservice: $wpdb->service('users')...), you would only have one line to change in your __get method. I personally would use a real getter and a real attribute for it, with a service injection on the class attribute...